# JQuery - hide a set of divs/images one by one randomly

Tags: jquery, animation, random

I have a set of visible divs/or images. by clicking one item, I'd like to hide the other divs/images. But it should be
- randomly
- one by one with either fadeOut() out or hide().
- (maybe animated)

My HTML:

```
<DIV class="myDivBox">Box no 1</DIV>
<DIV class="myDivBox">Box no 2</DIV>
<DIV class="myDivBox">Box no 3</DIV>
<DIV class="myDivBox">Box no 4</DIV>

<DIV class="myDivBox">Box no 5</DIV>
<DIV class="myDivBox">Box no 6</DIV>
<DIV class="myDivBox">Box no 7</DIV>
<DIV class="myDivBox">Box no 8</DIV>

<DIV class="myDivBox">Box no 9</DIV>
<DIV class="myDivBox">Box no 10</DIV>
<DIV class="myDivBox">Box no 11</DIV>
<DIV class="myDivBox">Box no 12</DIV>
```

My Code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // I know, this will hide all items of class .itembox
    $(".item_box").click(function (event)
    {

        $(".item_box").random().fadeOut(); // using a random class to hide 

    });
});
```

I am using the random plugin available at [github](http://github.com/Bastes/jQuery.Random/blob/master/jquery.random.js):

```
(function($) 
{
  jQuery.fn.random = function(num) {
  num = parseInt(num);
  if (num > this.length) return this.pushStack(this);
  if (! num || num < 1) num = 1;
  var to_take = new Array();
  this.each(function(i) { to_take.push(i); });
  var to_keep = new Array();
  var invert = num > (this.length / 2);
  if (invert) num = this.length - num;
  for (; num > 0; num--) {
  for (var i = parseInt(Math.random() * to_take.length); i > 0; i--)
  to_take.push(to_take.shift());
  to_keep.push(to_take.shift());
}
if (invert) to_keep = to_take;
return this.filter(function(i) { return $.inArray(i, to_keep) != -1; });
};
}) (jQuery);
```

Is there a way I can have this even without the random plugin?
Thanks

Comment: did you mean to have the same class for 'item_box' and 'myDivBox'?

Comment: sorry, I mean "myDivBox". thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will randomly hide one of the visible boxes when you click the `item_box` element:

```
$(function(){
  $(".item_box").click(function() {
    var $visible = $(".myDivBox:visible");
    $visible.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $visible.length)).hide('slow');
  });
});
```

This will hide all boxes at randomly chosen times within five seconds:

```
$(function(){
  $(".item_box").click(function() {
    $(".myDivBox").each(function(i, e){
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(e).hide('slow');
      }, Math.random() * 5000);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: very nice! Tested any works smooth. Thanks (Typo: Math.random...)